# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta con campos y tabla opcional en SQL? (Con GBD PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

Necesito que de una forma segura y eficiente, poder hacer una consulta a una tabla opcional con campos opcionales. Por ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT
    $1, $2, $3
FROM
    $4
```

Que si alguno de los parámetros recibidos no tiene valor, sea nulo o vacío, que haga la consulta con los parámetros que si tengan valor. ¿Hay forma de hacer esto?

Nota: Actualmente, utilizo Go como lenguaje de programación y lib/pq como driver.

Editado:

Para aclarar, necesito lo siguiente:

Que no importa si coloco

```sql
SELECT
    id, name
FROM
    users
```

o si coloco:

```sql
SELECT
    name, email
FROM
    users
```

Debo ejecutarlo con esto:

```golang
stmt.QueryRow(&user.id, &user.name, &user.email)
```

Y, como dije, si alguno de esos parámetros no es pedido en la consulta, que simplemente ignore la asignación de valor y siga con el otro.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias estar utilizando un generador de SQL, como por ejemplo [squirrel](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel).

Por ejemplo:

```
users := sq.Select("*").From("users")
sql, args, err := users.toSQL()
// sql == "SELECT * FROM users"
```

Comment: Caigo en lo mismo, debido a que al momento de ejecutar la consulta, debo colocar en el orden correcto, acorde con la consulta, los parámetros punteros donde caerán los valores.